# High-scale signal processing in R

Tags: r, signal-processing, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have high-dimensional data, for brain signals, that I would like to explore using R.

Since I am a data scientist I really do not work with Matlab, but R and Python. Unfortunately, the team I am working with is using Matlab to record the signals. Therefore, I have several questions for those of you who are interested in data science.

The Matlab files, recorded data, are single objects with the following dimensions:
1000*32*6000

**1000:** denotes the sampling rate of the signal.

**32:** denotes the number of channels.

**6000:** denotes the time in seconds, so that is 1 hour and 40 minutes long.

**The questions/challenges I am facing:**

I converted the "mat" files I have into CSV files, so I can use them in R.
However, CSV files are 2 dimensional files with the dimensions: 1000*192000.

1. the CSV files are rather large, about 1.3 gigabytes. **Is there a
   better way to convert "mat" files into something compatible with R,
   and smaller in size?** I have tried "R.matlab" with readMat, but it is
   not compatible with the 7th version of Matlab; so I tried to save as V6 version, but it says "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.7 Gb"
2. the time it takes to read the CSV file is rather long! It takes
       about 9 minutes to load the data. That is using "fread" since the
       base R function read.csv takes forever. **Is there a better way to
       read files faster?**
3. Once I read the data into R, it is 1000*192000; while it is actually
       1000*32*6000. **Is there a way to have multidimensional object in R,
       where accessing signals and time frames at a given time becomes
       easier.** *like dataset[1007,2], which would be the time frame of the
       1007 second and channel 2.* The reason I want to access it this way
       is to compare time frames easily and plot them against each other.

Any answer to any question would be appreciated.

Comment: R does have "higher" dimensional data structures: `arrays` but you also use lists. `data.table` and `ff` among many others may help with reading into R.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good reference for reading large CSV files:  https://rpubs.com/msundar/large_data_analysis A key takeaway is to assign the datatype for each column that you are reading versus having the read function decide based on the content.

Comment: I looked at the resource, and I am actually using their alternative method through fread, but it is still 9 minutes loading time.